# SELECT query for two variables in the same table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am asking you how can I mimic this logic in SQL:

```
SELECT var1, var2 FROM table1,WHERE var1 = COUNT(table1.status == 1) AND var2 = COUNT(table2.status == 2)
```

I want to store in `var1` the number of entries that have `status = 1` and in `var2` the number of entries which have `status = 2` in a single `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` combined with `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS var1,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS var2
FROM table1 t1;
```

Alternatively you can use `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(t1.status = 1) AS var1,
   SUM(t1.status = 2) AS var2
FROM table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your table is large and has an index on the `status` column, you need to be able to use an index to get fast exection (two index lookups are faster than one table scan), and that requires to filter the rows with WHERE.

If you can handle the result as two rows, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE status = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE status = 2;
```

If you need the results in two columns, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE status = 1) AS var1,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE status = 2) AS var2;
```

Comment: This would be more efficient if the rows were *wide* as well as the table having lots of rows.  If the `status` column is the only column in the table (unlikely), then using the index would not be a performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want set two result difference in two variables in a one row this is the option.

```
SELECT 
   @var1 = t1.column,
   @var2 = t2.column
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON 
       a.column = 'value' AND 
       b.column = 'value2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery,Fetch count using count() method of sql

So,

```
SELECT var1, var2 FROM table1 WHERE var1 = (SELECT count(*) from table 1 where table1.status == 1) AND var2 = (SELECT count(*) from table 1 where table1.status == 2)
```

Comment: This would require that the table already has columns named `var1` and var2`.